# How to find the general solution of a system of ODEs?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I am trying to understand an example of Lawrance Perko, the problem being 
\begin{align}
\dot{x}_1 &=-x_1-3x_2\\
\dot{x}_2 &=2x_2
\end{align}

Which can be written in the form $\dot{x}=Ax$ where :

\begin{align}
A=
\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & -3 \\
0  & 2
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

The eigen values of A are $\lambda_{1}=-1$,$\lambda_{1}=2$ and the eigenvectors are $v_1=[1,0]$ and $v_2=[-1,1]$ respectively. The matrix P and the decoupling matrix $P^{-1}$ are given by,
\begin{align}
P=\begin{bmatrix}
1 &-1 \\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix},P^{-1}=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

Under the co-ordinate transform $y=P^{-1}x$ the linearly uncoupled system is given by:

\begin{align}
\dot{y_1}=-y_1\\
\dot{y_2}=2y_2
\end{align}

Which has the general solution $y_1=c_1\exp(-t)$, $y_2=c_2\exp(2t)$. Now the general solution of the original system is iven by:
\begin{align}\tag{1}
x(t)=P\begin{bmatrix}
e^{-t} & 0 \\
0 & e^{2t}
\end{bmatrix}P^{-1}c
\end{align}

Where $c=x(0)$, or equivalently by

[image]

---

What I don't understand is the last step. According to my calculation $y=P^{-1}x$ so $x_1=y_1-y_2$, $x_2 = y_2$. So $x_1$ should be $c_1 e^{-t}-c_2e^{2t}$ and not $c_1 e^{-t}+c_2(e^{-t}-e^{2t})$ \ref{1}

Comment: I just noticed: it should be a $-3$ in $A$, not a $3$. Although, this does not  affect the eigenvalues, but it will affect the eigenvectors.

Comment: I calculated the eigenvectors using -3 on my notebook so those are correct. It's just a typo here.

Comment: @Harry49, so can you suggest what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting $t=0$ in the solution proposed by the author of the OP gives $x_1 (0) = c_1 - c_2$, which is in contradiction with the definition of $c = x (0)$. Equation $(1)$ is correct. If $y = P^{-1} x$, then we have
$$y_1 (t) = e^{-t} y_1 (0) ,\quad y_2 (t) = e^{2t} y_2 (0),$$
and in particular
$$x_1 (t) = y_1 (t) - y_2 (t) . $$
Now, it remains to express $y (0)$ in terms of $x (0) = c$, i.e.
$$y_1 (0) = c_1 + c_2 ,\quad y_2 (0) = c_2,$$
which gives the result of the book.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this fact. Given $\dot x_1(t)=-x_1-3x_2$ and $\dot x_2=2x_2$. Adding this two equation gives $\dot x_1+\dot x_2=-(x_1+x_2)$, so that $\frac{d}{dt}(\dot x_1+\dot x_2)=-(x_1+x_2)$ which gives $(x_1+x_2)(t)=c_1e^{-t}$ and this very well agrees with the answer you found out.

Comment: I now understand that my solution is also correct. I also found out to get to the solution given in the book(perko) you need to use (1).

Comment: This fact is true, even if it's nothing more than writing the time evolution of $y=P^{-1} x$. However, if $c=x (0)$, it must be $(x_1 + x_2)(t) = (c_1 + c_2)e^{-t}$.

Answer (score 0):

The solution $x_1=y_1−y_2$, $x_2=y_2$ is also correct as mentioned by @Nobagoto. To get to the answer in the book you need to use equation $(1)$. The matrices $P$ and $P^{-1}$ are known so $x(t)$ can be easily calculated.